# Save manual data in log file django

Tags: django, logging, django-rest-framework

hi I am creating a log file in django , and my settings.py file is like

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/User/Desktop/customapp/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

I just want to save in log file  like , **at 12:00 user visted [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)**
I am trying to save data in it like   **logger.info('www.mywebsite.com')**

But nothing is happening

**EDIT**

I am getting output in file like

```
GET /report/late_tasks_count/ HTTP/1.1" 200 74
"GET /report/late_tasks_count/ HTTP/1.1" 200 74
(0.000) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.001) SHOW FULL TABLES; args=None
(0.002) SELECT `django_migrations`.`app`, `django_migrations`.`name` FROM `django_migrations`; args=()
"GET /report/late_tasks_count/ HTTP/1.1" 200 74
```

while I just want to keep     `"GET /report/late_tasks_count/ HTTP/1.1" 200 74`

Comment: [logger formatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu  I just want to add this data in file , but on first place I am unable to add to logger file which is main concern